# Get a list of pending items of a certain type in Azure offline sync

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-web-app-service

I understand we can get a count of pending items by

`PendingChanges = manager.MobileServiceClient.SyncContext.PendingOperations;`

but this only gets me a total count of pending items. what should I do if I need to show a list of all pending items yet to be synced of a certain type? 
Is there a way we can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is an event that you can subscribe to for getting each event.  When you initialize the sync context, use:

`await client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store, StoreTrackingOptions.NotifyLocalAndServerOperations);`

You can subscribe to store operation events like so:

`subscription = client.EventManager.Subscribe<StoreOperationCOmpletedEvent>(StoreOperationEventHandler);`

You can get a wiki edition of this note here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/wiki/How-to-get-notifications-of-new-records-added-during-Pull-operation

Comment: Thanks Adrian I will give it a try.

Comment: There's an open GitHub issue to get the pending operations themselves: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/issues/2

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with a method like this:

```
public async Task<string> GetPendingOperationsAsync()
{
    var query = MobileServiceTableQueryDescription.Parse("__operations", null);
    var jsonResult = await myClient.SyncContext.Store.ReadAsync(query);
    return jsonResult.ToString();
}
```

All I cared about was getting a string I could pass on to error reporting, but you can drop the `ToString()` part if you want to inspect the data as a JToken tree programatically.  Also, instead of `null` I believe you can pass a query into the `Parse()` call to filter your results, for instance by type.

Obviously, this relies on the Azure Mobile Services internal implementation, so use at your own risk.